# Session "name" is not carrying over to other pages

Tags: php, session

I have been having a little trouble getting my session variable to carry over to my other pages.

I am still new to this site so I am not sure how to show code here so I used CSSDeck: http://cssdeck.com/labs/jxtfublm

The bottom box shows the confirmation page of the log in, and I have tested it. This part works and information is 100% correct, but the first box is the home page where I am trying to use the session to show the same user. The call echo $_SESSION["name"]; does not display anything -> Which means to me that the session name variable is not carried over.

Comment: you miss `session_start()` at the beginning of each page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ist of all make sure you are using `session_start();` in your files on top level declaration.

Now in your code that you shared in image link you are not using comparison you are using assigning.

```
if($_SESSION['name'] = "") // assigning the value not compare.

if($_SESSION['name'] == "") // comparing the value not assign.
```

**More explanation:**

```
= assign value to variable
== compare with value
=== compare with value and data type
```

Comment: Always recommend Yoda conditionals I do. `if("" = $_SESSION['name'])` returns errors always.

Comment: @jay-blanchard bro didn't try yet.. :)

Comment: Just got back, that small change made it work! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Execute `session_start();` on top of every page you want to have access to the session variables. Note that you have to run it before anything else in your page.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply, but I already have "session_start();" on top of every page! I have checks to make sure that there is something in "names" but it will not display like : http://puu.sh/mVZWs/1d83cb0870.png , and this is the code: http://puu.sh/mW003/d4e593caad.png

Comment: Do you by any chance execute session_destroy() accidently?

Comment: Here, you have if ($_SESSION["name"] = "" etc etc. Use == or better === to compare the value, you are now actually assigning an empty string the the variable

Comment: Hi I do not call session destroy anywhere I havnt gotten up to that haha. Will look at the = problem mentioned soon I have class right now, thanks!